Playwright expect().toBeVisible fails even though the locator exists
Playwright is giving me a hard time on basic selectors. In this test I have a simple test to click on the autoCompleteInput and fill inn a text, but the test never finds the selector even though I can see that the inputfield with the data-testid exists in the DOM (proved by tracing). What am I doing wrong? the only thing that makes this work is to set a page.waitForTimeout(5000) which I don't want to do.
is the expect function too strict? does it not wait?
our stack is NextJS with SSR on initial load. The frontend is running locally with data from a deployed test-environment
the test:
export const searchFor = async (page: Page, text: string) => {
  const autoCompleteInput = await page.getByPlaceholder(
    '[data-testid="autocompleteSearchInput"]',
  );
  await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid="autocompleteSearchInput"]');
  await expect(autoCompleteInput).toBeVisible();

  await autoCompleteInput.click();
  await autoCompleteInput.fill(text);
  const autoCompleteList = await page.locator(
    '[data-testid="autoCompleteList"]',
  );
  await expect(autoCompleteList).toBeVisible();
};

tracing:

the error itself:
Error: Timed out 10000ms waiting for expect(locator).toBeVisible()

Locator: getByPlaceholder('[data-testid="autocompleteSearchInput"]')
Expected: visible
Received: <element(s) not found>
Call log:
  - expect.toBeVisible with timeout 10000ms
  - waiting for getByPlaceholder('[data-testid="autocompleteSearchInput"]')


   at partials\autoComplete\autoCompleteHelper.ts:8

   6 |   );
   7 |   await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid="autocompleteSearchInput"]');
>  8 |   await expect(autoCompleteInput).toBeVisible();
     |                                   ^
   9 |
  10 |   await autoCompleteInput.click();
  11 |   await autoCompleteInput.fill(text);


Can you share the page? Visibility !== existence. An aside: you can use getByTestId("...") rather than locator('[data-testid="..."]') to shorten your code a bit.

nevermind I was testing .getByPlaceholder earlier and forgot to change back to .getByTestId
